# How can I reduce the long compilation time?

Tags: compiling, visual-studio-code

##### translation by DeepL.com

Description of the problem: I use Visual Studio Code on Windows, together with the extension "LaTeX Workshop" and the LaTeX distribution "TeX Live". Unfortunately, compiling LaTeX documents takes an unusually long time, even for small changes or small documents. This causes a decrease in my work speed and efficiency.

I would like to know if there are ways to optimize compilation times and make the process more efficient. Are there specific settings in Visual Studio Code, recommendations for configuring LaTeX Workshop or TeX Live, or best practices I can use to improve compilation speed?

##### original

Beschreibung des Problems:
Ich verwende Visual Studio Code unter Windows, zusammen mit der Erweiterung "LaTeX Workshop" und der LaTeX-Distribution "TeX Live". Leider dauert die Kompilierung von LaTeX-Dokumenten ungewöhnlich lange, selbst bei kleinen Änderungen oder kleinen Dokumenten. Dies führt zu einer Beeinträchtigung meiner Arbeitsgeschwindigkeit und Effizienz.

Ich würde gerne wissen, ob es Möglichkeiten gibt, die Kompilierungszeiten zu optimieren und den Prozess effizienter zu gestalten. Gibt es bestimmte Einstellungen in Visual Studio Code, Empfehlungen zur Konfiguration von LaTeX Workshop oder TeX Live, oder bewährte Methoden, die ich anwenden kann, um die Kompilierungsgeschwindigkeit zu verbessern?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) This is an English speaking website. As a consequence, could you post your question in English please?

Comment: I provided a translation using DeepL.com. But the question is unfortunately too generic to receive sensible answers. More details on the specific problem are needed. I can compile long documents (300 or more pages) in just a few seconds.

Comment: A few questions: 1) Why does it have to be VSC? I.e. why can't you use a different editor, like TexMaker? 2) Is there a difference when you compile your .tex files from the commandline? Which may lead to: 3) How is VSC configured for Latex? 4) Who did the configuration?